# Validate WPF Polygon before render

Tags: wpf, polygon, ellipse

I have a Polygon that moves inside an Ellipse. The Polygon's X and Y coordinates are updated by MVVM binding using a RenderTransform TranslateTransform.

I want to prevent the Polygon to move  outside the Ellipse, but I am not sure how to do it. I thought about a validator, but a validator will get just the X or the Y update, and to determine where the Polygon is I need the X and Y at the same time... If the Ellipse was a square things will be easier since the bounds are constant.

I update the Polygon's X, Y and Angle using MVVM. How can I prevent it to go outside the Ellipse?

I am thinking on maybe intercept the render and prevent it to be render if the new X and Y are outside the Ellipse, but I don't feel this is the right thing to do, and I also am not even sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you do the validation in your viewmodel?

Comment: No, because the X and Y positions come from the Model

Comment: So? The viewmodel should have access to the model, right? Otherwise how would it be able to pass the X, Y properties to the transform in the view?

Comment: The Model makes a new X, Y,  angle position, and each of these properties have a NotifyPropertyChanged, the VM have an instance of the Model, and the View binds to the instance of the Model in the ViewModel

Comment: Some people think only the VM can fire a property changed, and makes lots of wraps, but Microsofts documents point it clearly that the Model can fire them as well, and I find it a lot easier than programming lots and lots of wraps

Comment: Or are you suggesting that I get the notification on the viewmodel and then update some new property on the view model or not? Still X and Y and Angle will come each at its own time and I need X and Y as a pair to validate if the Polygon will be inside the ellipse

Comment: From what layer do you perform the X and Y changes? The VM? Do you have access to the Ellipse Size and Location in the VM? What you need is a layer (Preferably the VM) where you have access to all informations required. If you perform the changes of the X and Y values in the VM and you have the Ellipse's Location and Size in the VM you can solve this quite simple.

Comment: Yes I know,  but the update is in the Model, and I don't want to give the Model the size of the ellipse... The Model represents a robot, so it's position is updated regularly, I agree that the VM will make it easier, but I don't want to break the way things are working